# Where can I find Ethiopian electoral constituency and district (woreda) boundaries data?

Tags: data, administrative-boundaries

I am a PhD student in Development Studies in Oxford.

I'm trying to find a map of the Ethiopian electoral boundaries. These are not the same as the district (woreda) boundaries - districts can be in more than one electoral constituency (see this list of constituencies and the districts they cover for an example http://www.electionethiopia.org/en/amhara/167-north-wello.html).

I already have shapefiles of the district boundaries.

Any help would be amazing, even pointers to international sites that cover a number of countries and might cover Ethiopia.

Answer (score 2):

Check if http://www.gadm.org/ has the wanted subdivisions. Also consider contacting their government if all else fails.

Comment: +1 Global Administrative Areas (GADM)

Answer (score 2):

[Humanitarian Response](http://cod.humanitarianresponse.info/) has Woreda boundaries listed under [admin_level3.zip](http://cod.humanitarianresponse.info/country-region/ethiopia) (i.e. Administrative Boundaries > Most Recent Known Changes > admin_level3.zip).  The attached image shows the Woreda boundaries.

[image]

Comment: Hi all! I checked both GADM and Humanitarian Response. These are very helpful for the woreda (district) boundaries. But woredas aren't the same as electoral constituencies. If one looks at the election board site (e.g. http://www.electionethiopia.org/en/amhara/166-south-gonder.html), one can see that there is often more than one woreda in a constituency or, more problematically, more than one constituency in a woreda. I want to be able to assign each woreda an electoral result, and sometimes a woreda will be in more than one constituency with differing results.